# What is the correct code to use when using JavaScript to read or write to a Google Firestore Database through a Google Cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a game in Unreal Engine and I want to have some values stored on a cloud database and access the info (read or write) through cloud functions so I chose Google Firestore for that.
I have been trying to read (I thought I should succeed with this before moving on to writting) to the Firestore database but for some reason I can't get the results that I want. So let's say I have the following setup in my database:

[my firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S39u.jpg)

and I want to get the player level from a specific user who's ID (and the server) will be provided by the client (the data from the client are transfered correctly to the function as I checked with a console.log on lines 74+75). I have this function that tries to read from the database:

```
exports.getplayerlevel = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const db =admin.firestore();

  // get player id in order to locate the corresponding value
  const playeridnumber = String(data.values[0]); // player id
  const currentserver = String(data.values[1]); // currentserver

  console.log("playerid"+ playeridnumber);
  console.log("currentserver"+ currentserver);
  console.log("test7.4");

  // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
  const playerstats = await db.collection("servers").doc("/"+ currentserver).collection("players").doc("/"+ playeridnumber);

  playerstats.get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          console.log("doc was not found");
          throw new functions.https.HttpsError("nofound", "Docu not exist.");
        }

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        const fieldValue = doc.level;
        console.log("the end result should be "+ fieldValue);
        return ([fieldValue]);
      });
});
```

Currently with the above code I don't get the level returned and I am missing why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried also to replace the "const playerstats" with:

```
const playerstats = await db.collection("servers").doc(currentserver).collection("players").doc(playeridnumber);
```

That also didn't work.

Comment: What si the output of something like a   console.log('Document data:', doc.data());

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors. If you post the code as text I'll be able to copy and adapt it.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec You are right, my bad. I've updated my post with the code

Comment: @VasundharaMehta I haven't tried that and I don't think I've seen this anywhere used. I'll check it out and if I get any results I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the trick (untested) but it depends on the way you call the Callable Cloud Function from the front-end and pass the `playerId` and `currentserver` values. I'm not sure that `String(data.values[0])` works the way you expect. Do you get the correct value when logging it with `console.log("playerid" + playeridnumber);`?

Can you share your front-end code in your question?

So, in the below code we've adapted the following points:

- Avoid mixing `async/await` and `then()`
- The `get()` method is asynchronous so you need to use `await` when you call it, not when you define the [`DocumentReference`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html)
- Don't put slashes when defining the `DocumentReference`
- To get the field value you need to use the [`data()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html#data) method of the `DocumentSnapshot` (or the [`get()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html#get) method)

---

```js
exports.getplayerlevel = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const db = admin.firestore();

  // get player id in order to locate the corresponding value
  const playeridnumber = String(data.values[0]); // <=== To be confirmed as it depnds how uou call the Cloud Function
  const currentserver = String(data.values[1]); // <=== To be confirmed as it depnds how uou call the Cloud Function

  console.log("playerid" + playeridnumber);
  console.log("currentserver" + currentserver);
  console.log("test7.4");

  // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
  const playerStatsSnapshot = await db
    .collection("servers")
    .doc(currentserver)
    .collection("players")
    .doc(playeridnumber)
    .get();

  if (!playerStatsSnapshot.exists) {
    console.log("doc was not found");
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("nofound", "Docu not exist.");
  } else {
    const fieldValue = playerStatsSnapshot.data().level;
    console.log("the end result should be " + fieldValue);
    return { level: fieldValue };
  }
});
```

Comment: I just tried what you posted and it did not find the level number. The console.log that I used to check if the `playerId` and `currentserver` are giving the correct values. The error on the console is this:

`Unhandled error Error: Unknown error code: nofound.
    at new HttpsError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:75:19)
    at /workspace/index.js:88:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:438:26`

Comment: Can you share in your question the code you use for calling the Cloud Function from the front-end?

Comment: I'm afrain it would be a bit complicated to send you the front end code as I am using Unreal Engine's blueprints and I have installed a plugin for the API for Google Features. This is the plugin [link](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/firebase-features). Since the functions run correctly though and the variables are passed correctly too I don't think it's a front end issue. Even if I didn't try to use any variables from the front end and I specified with `string` the path of the document it still wouldn't work.

Comment: What is the code at line 88 of your `index.js` file?

Comment: IMPORTANT: Are you aware that to call a Callable Cloud Function (`functions.https.onCall`) you must use one of the Firebase Client SDKs, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd)? If you don't use the Client SDk you need to implement a complex [protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).

Comment: Everything related to SDK is taken care of by the creator of the plugin. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to call the function. Now I do call it and I can even get results back to my client. It's only the communication to the database part that I can't figure out. 

The 88th line of my `index.js` file is the following:
`throw new functions.https.HttpsError("nofound", "Docu not exist.");`

Comment: I don't know why you get an error at this line since the code is correct (for Cloud Functions 1st generation). But if you get there it means that there isn't any document at `db.collection("servers").doc(currentserver).collection("players").doc(playeridnumber)`

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes any difference but I'm actually trying to get a `FIELD` that is located in the document `playerid`. You can check the screenshot at my post to see my database structure.

Comment: Arghh… there was an error in my code. It should be `const fieldValue = playerStatsSnapshot.data().level;` and not `const fieldValue = doc.data().level;`. I copied the `const fieldValue = doc.level; ` line from your code and forget to adapt it to the new name of the `DocumentSnapshot` variable… Answer adapted.

Comment: I just tried that and unfortunately I still got an error on the function log.

Unhandled error Error: Unknown error code: nofound.
    at new HttpsError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:75:19)
    at /workspace/index.js:88:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:438:26

Comment: Are you sure there is a document at db.collection("servers").doc(currentserver).collection("players").doc(playeridnumber)? Is your CF deployed or you use the emulator?

Comment: Main collection is "servers" which has the document "currentserver" which has another collection called "players" which has a document with the "playeridnumber" and that has a field called "level" with a numeric value. 
I am always deploying from my terminal, usually only the functions ( `firebase deploy --only functions` ) but I also tried to deploy everything as well. 
If you see my code I always have a console.log("test X.X") and I do that to check when I get the logs of the function that my function was succesfully update. It works fine.

Comment: I don’t think I can help you anymore… The code in my answer is correct, I’ve triple checked. Maybe one last remark: doc and collection names are case sensitive so `Server1` value is not equivalent to `server1`.

Comment: Here's some progress that might help. I realised that it's the doc that can't be found so I tried to only specify the path with `strings`. That didn't work. Then I removed the second `.collection` and `.doc` and that worked! Here's how it looked like:

`const playerStatsSnapshot = await db
      .collection("servers")
      .doc(currentserver)
      .get();`

So by removing the:

`.collection("players")
 .doc(playeridnumber)`

it seems to work! The problem is definitely not at the names but at how I'm addressing the path. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I guess that the value of `currentserver` is `Server1` so it would mean that you have a document at the path `servers/Server1` which has a field named `level`.

Comment: Yes, I manually added one `field` called `level` just for testing and it works and the value of `currentserver` is always `Server1` for now. My initial setup though (with the extra collection and doc) is still the one I need to implement. I have to find out why it doesn't work when I add those.

Comment: I found this [link](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166) to an article you wrote about listing multiple subcollections. Any chance the answer to my problem could be in the 2nd approach?

Comment: This article explains how to list (sub)collections when you don’t know their names. In your case it is different since you know the paths. If it works with `playerStatsSnapshot = await db     .collection("servers").doc(currentserver).get();` it should work for   `playerStatsSnapshot = await db     .collection("servers").doc(currentserver).collection("players")  .doc(playeridnumber).get();` IF there is really a document at this last path (i.e. the valu of the `playeridnumber` variable DOES correspond to a document ID (same case, no space, etc…)

Comment: So you need to thoroughly verify/debug the values of `currentserver` and `playeridnumber` and be sure they exactly correspond to documents present in your database.

Comment: What's interesting is that even if I specify the path with strings while following exactly the names as I have them in the database, it still won't find the document. This tells me that it has nothing to do with the values and if they are passed correctly from the client.

Comment: Can you try to fetch the document from a Client SDK (i.e. from a front end)?

Comment: And can you add to your question: the screenshot of the Firestore database with all the collections and docs AND how you declare the path with the hardcoded strings. There may be an error that 4 eyes will detect ;-)

Comment: Ok I have some news. I've been testing back and forth in Unreal Engine and kept updating the JS code to see what's wrong. Here's what I found that's really interesting.

So I'm sending a string from the client with 17 numbers for the player id. When I try to find the corresponding document that always fails. BUT if there was a document with text like "playerid" for example that works fine! It's the only-numeric named document that's been difficult to get.

Thank you so much for sticking with me though this. I really appreciate it.

Comment: A quick update. When I add some text before the numeric value, for example `pid76561198034360180` instead of just `76561198034360180`, I get the document with no problem! So I guess I can find a workaround and add to the client id a prefix "pid" which seems to solve this problem! :)
 Would you mind sharing with me how to write to that fielf instead of read?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255032/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-leftblue).